# Vector vs scalar

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I read the following about vectors vs scalars from "Parallel Programming with MPI":

> Without vectors each basic operation will have to be fetched and decoded n times. With vector instructions, each of the basic instructions only needs to be issued once. The difference is somewhat analogous to the difference between the Fortran 77 code
>
> ```
> do i=1,n
>    z(i) = x(i) + y(i)
> end do
> ```
>
> and the equivaent Fortran 90 code
>
> ```
> z(1:n) = x(1:n) + y(1:n)
> ```

To compare performance of vectors vs scalars I wrote the program:

```
  program vector
  parameter (n=1000000, iruns=4)
  real x(n),y(n),z(n),t1,t2,time
  integer clock_rate,count_max

  do i=1,n
    x(i)=i
    y(i)=i*2
  enddo

  time=0.
  do irun=1,iruns
    call cpu_time(t1)
    do i=1,n
      z(i) = x(i) + y(i)
    enddo
    call cpu_time(t2)
    time = time + t2 - t1
  enddo
  time = time/real(iruns)
  print '(a,e12.5)','sum z = ',sum(z)
  print '(2(a,e12.5,2x))','time serial = ',time,'sec'

  time=0.
  do irun=1,iruns
    call cpu_time(t1)
    z(1:n) = x(1:n) + y(1:n)
    call cpu_time(t2)
    time = time + t2 - t1
  enddo
  time = time/real(iruns)
  print '(a,e12.5)','sum z = ',sum(z)
  print '(2(a,e12.5,2x))','time vector = ',time,'sec'
  end
```

which prints the output:

```
sum z =  0.15004E+13
time serial =  0.39995E-02  sec
sum z =  0.15004E+13
time vector =  0.12497E-02  sec
```

My question is, given that vector operations are much faster than serial (3x for this example) when would it be preferable to use serial operations over vector operations?

Comment: Which compiler options have you used? Which compiler? Have yo used any parallelization? `cpu_time()` is **useless** for parallel programs. Really useless, avoid it. And questions about performance without the details about the compiler and the options are used are useless as well.

Comment: And, BTW, read https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this to see why to avoid the `(1:n)`.

Comment: I used gfortran without any compiler options. No parallelization. I already knew that cpu_time is useless for parallel programs and that system_time is preferred because it measures wall time but that was **not my question**.

Comment: Performance measurements without any compiler optimizations are useless as well. You can get almost any result from various compilers. How the compiler is able to optimize stuff is what matters. The point is that there should not be any difference between the two variants and there is not much reason why the array operations (which you call "vectorized") should be faster. They are actually sometimes slower.

Comment: why the mpi tag?

Comment: The serial with an !$OMP clause will be faster again.
Something the compiler's optimisation is fastest, and sometimes the !$OMP, Sometimes putting the inner loop into an elemental function, and often the alignment of the vector on 64-byte boundary is worthwhile.